# How do I seal off a cavern in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

As I was digging up/down staircases straight down the Z-level, I hit upon a cavern. I'd like to seal it off now so I don't get attacked by the underground mobs. There's only one up/down staircase that I need to seal off. How do I seal it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Jupotter notes, a [constructed](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Construction) wall or floor will do the trick.

If you're in a hurry, and happen to have some spare [doors](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Door) or [hatch covers](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Hatch_cover) lying nearby, you may want to build one of those first and forbid it once it's done — I believe building a door or hatch is faster than building a construction.  However, you should generally not rely on doors and hatches alone to seal off passages unless you like living dangerously, since many tougher enemies, including [forgotten beasts](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Forgotten_beast), can [destroy them](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Building_destroyer).

However, there are two notable exceptions to that, one of which may be relevant here: building destroyers can't destroy [artifact](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Legendary_artifact) doors or hatches, and, for some reason (which might constitute a bug) they [can't destroy hatches from below](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Building_destroyer#Destroying_from_underneath).

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of ways to close a staircase, unless the mechanics have massively changed since I last played DF.

Your easiest way, that keeps your options open for the future, is to build a stone floor over the top of the hole. You could also craft and build a stone hatch and then lock it. If the up/down is part of a staircase shaft then you will have to go up a level to create a down that connects to an up on the level where your original staircase ran out. For a permanent block, you can mine out the staircase and plug it with stone.

[image: A Lame Paint diagram :D]

Answer (score 3):

You can put a floor on the staircase, it will prevent anything from coming trough.

Floors are build with <kbd>b-C-f</kbd>.

Comment: yep, but iirc you can't build on an up/down (as it occupies bottom middle and top of a block). As this is at the bottom of a shaft of up/downs he will have to mine out the one above the hole first.

Comment: Yup, you're right, i forget that. In fact, it's the Up staircase itself that block the construction, IIRC. Your solution works best.